# The system cannot find the path specified in kony studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, temenos-quantum

I'm working with KonyOne Studio to build and test apps but when I am launch android emulator then
that error showing in cmd:

```
 - AVD: konyavdmap
 - APK: E:\KonyWorkspace1\temp\demo\build\luaandroid\dist\luavmandroid.apk
 - AppId: demo
 - Emulator arguments: "  "
 - Package: com.orgname.demo
 - serialnumber: emulator-5554
 - profileapp: false
 - devlang: js
 - Web Selected: false
 - adb.exe
 - com.orgname.demo
 - emulator-5554
 - 5554
 - Launching emulator
 - * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
 - * daemon started successfully *
 - unknown
 - Waiting for HOME to launch
 - Waiting..
- waiting for device -
```

The Android SDK is located in:

> PATH: C:\Kony\ImageMagick;C:\Kony\Ant\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;D:\Kony Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;D:\Kony Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools;
>
> JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

And I got error in console:

```
 - emu:
 - [echo] emulator.dir: D:\Kony Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools
 - [echo] emu loc: D:\Kony Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools\emulator.exe
 - [echo] apk.file: E:\KonyWorkspace1\temp\demo\build\luaandroid\dist\luavmandroid.apk
 - [echo] appID: demo
 - [echo] avdname: konyavdmap
 - [echo] cmd args: 
 - [echo] android packagename : com.orgname.demo
 - [echo] web.selected : false
 -  [echo] Jetty.IP : 0.0.0.0.(dummy ip address)
 - [echo] Jetty.Port : 8888
 - [echo] AVD name is konyavdmap
 - [exec-script] The system cannot find the path specified.
 - [exec-script] Result: 255
```

Everything is good but it didn't launch android emulator. Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had problems when my Android SDK was installed to a pathname with a space in it (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`).  The emulator had intermittent issues launching, and the debugger would always fail.

If you give Kony Studio an Android SDK path without spaces, it will be a lot happier.  While most of the time, installing to their default locations causes less issues, this is one of those exceptions.

To fix it without re-installing anything, you can create a symlink or junction to a directory that has no spaces.  The Kony Studio default is `C:\Kony` which has no spaces.  That will be a good place to put this junction.

Since you installed your Kony Studio to `C:\Kony`, add a junction to your Kony install directory that points to your Android SDK:

```
cd C:\Kony\
mklink /j android-sdk "D:\Kony Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk"
```

Open `C:\Kony\android-sdk` and verify that you see the `platform-tools` and the `tools` directories.

- Go into your Studio, and open the `Window | Preferences` dialog.
- Select `Kony Dev Studio \ Build`
- Change your `Android Home` value to link created above

  - In this case `C:\Kony\android-sdk`

Try running the emulator again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the path in environment variables.

```
ANT_HOME             D:\kony\Ant

JAVA_HOME            D:\kony\jdk1.6.0_32;

path:    %Path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;D:\androidsdk\tools;D:\androidsdk\platform-tools;D:\kony\ImageMagick;D:\kony\Ant\bin;D:\kony\jdk1.6.0_32\bin;
```

**To run the app in emulator:**
You have to map the AVD which you created using android AVD Manager and kony studio. both avd name should be same.if nothing works then start emulator from AVD Manager first and then run the project with the same emulator which is mapped in knoy studio.